# What to write in the htaccess in order to detect browser language and point accordingly?

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, multi-language, plugin-polylang

On short:
I use **Polylang plugin** for my web but it's option to detect **browser language won't work** because **I need to use cache** in the whole site, including the homepage.

I have a bilingual website (english and spanish) which handles lots of Custom Post Type and Custom Fields data. This means that **I MUST use cache and CDN** (like Cloudflare) in order to achieve good speed and performance by serving static files.

This is not my field of expertise so I know little about this stuff. But, from what I've read, it seems like creating rewrite rules would be a good way to add language detection on front-page and show the user the best fit.

Someone mentioned the following code as a solution for the problem
https://github.com/polylang/polylang/issues/450#issuecomment-586484873

```
# BEGIN Language Redirect

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en|es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/ [L,R=302]

# END Language Redirect
```

> Edit: replaced "http" for "https" as pointed out by @MrWhite

But it didn't work for me. Maybe I'm writting the .htaccess file between the wrong lines or maybe those redirects conflict with my SSL redirects.

Information that might be relevant to help me:
· My hosting provider is Bluehost, i'm pretty shure server runs on apache
· I have SLL certificate and have ReallySimpleSSL plugin installed on my WordPress
· The subdirectories for mydomain.com/en and mydomain.com/es doesn't actually exist, It seems that Polylang plugin is only editing the URLs to make it look like

Is this the right way to do point a user according to it's browser language, from a cached website?

Comment: Since this is more of an .htaccess focused question I would suggest asking on StackOverflow. This site deals more specifically with WordPress code - although you are talking about a WP site it doesn't sound like the WP configuration applies much to the question.

Comment: I get your point. The thing is that WP, as well as some plugins, are also editing the .htaccess file and I would need someone who knows about what's going on in that file when using WP.

Also, maybe the answer to my problem is not via the .htaccess file, rather via some javascript code inserted through Code Snippets in the wp_head. I'd really prefer help from a Wordpress friendly developer since they know the field I'm deep into.

Comment: You might try a host support ticket or checking with the authors of Polylang. They would know more specifically about your setup. :)

Comment: "I MUST use cache and CDN" - What kind of caching? If you are relying heavily on client-side browser caching and/or CDN then the request may not even be reaching your origin server in order to process the language redirect? The directives you posted should work to redirect requests for the homepage **only**, although an obvious error is that you are redirecting to HTTP, not HTTPS (and you say you have "SSL redirects"). But as you suggest, these directives might be conflicting with other directives in the `.htaccess` file - order matters. They probably should not be "between" anything.

Comment: However, there's also the small matter that language redirects like this in `.htaccess` are unreliable and generally bad for SEO (although I suppose you are "only" redirecting the homepage - but this is usually the gateway to the rest of your site?). Search engine bots generally don't send an `Accept-Language` header at all, so will always be redirected to "en". The directives as posted will redirect to "en" (if this is a supported language), even if "es" might be the _preferred_ language.

Comment: I'm using disk caching for the webpages and serving all files (including images) through Cloudflare's CDN. Since my website is maily used as a Portfolio (updated every once in a while) and I don't allow comments nor use woocomerce, so serving static files doesn't present any problems for me. And it speeds up performance big time.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that info @MrWhite , thank you very much. I'll try adressing Polylang authors, as WebElaine suggested, as my last hope but it seems that I'll have to accept that what I want is too problematic. Thank you both for your time

Comment: If you post your entire `.htaccess` file with these directives in place then we can at least see if they are in the right place and whether there are any conflicts. Presumably the intention is to only redirect the homepage? So, a request for `/something` will not be redirected?

Comment: It's pretty long. I'll add it within the question if it helps. But first I must share some information that might be important and the main reason why the rewrites don't work for me: The multilingual plugin I use (Polylang) did not create a sub-folder for the different languages, instead it seems to be only appending the language to the URL (for example "mydomain.com/es/" but the directory doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @MrWhite I added my actual .htaccess (without the language redirect) code to the question as you requested. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: The idea was to see the `.htaccess` code _with_ the language redirect in-place to perhaps determine why it seemingly wasn't doing anything. "(Polylang) did not create a sub-folder for the different languages" - I'm not familiar with the plugin myself, but I wouldn't necessarily expect it to have to create physical directories for the lang codes? (It shouldn't have permission to create physical directories?) The language code would usually only be part of the URL, not the underlying file structure.

Comment: @MrWhite I tried pasting the code in different positions: before the "Really Simple SSL" lines, before "BEGIN WordPress" lines and at the very end. None of those seemed to work. I guess I'll have to contact the plugin's developers after all. I'll update when arriving at some conclusion. Thanks again!

Comment: Anywhere before the `BEGIN WordPress` section should have "worked". However, for this to work reliably it would need to bypass Cloudflare's cache on every request to the homepage (or every "new request" to the homepage - if that can be determined?) - which I think would be a problem. See this question on StackOverflow: [Respecting language header in cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713610/respecting-language-header-in-cloudflare)

Comment: Problematic indeed. I'll leave it as it is, then, without language detection for the time being. Thanks again for everything @MrWhite